# Functional Relationship Between Epsilon and Delta

Tags: limits, vector-analysis, epsilon-delta

In my textbook on vector calculus, I was studying up on the epsilon-delta definition of limits (new to me at the time). I believe I've understood what it's all about intuitively, and appreciate the rigour of it; however there was a statement (more of side note) that said something along the lines of "generally you must find a functional relationship between epsilon and delta". I don't have the book handy, and can't recall if it used the word "generally" or "usually", hence I'm now wondering if a functional relationship is necessary, or if there are other, "sneaky" ways to prove a limit converges using epsilon-delta. I appreciate any insight into the question. I remember reading a second definition that talked about a "neighborhood" around a point, but couldn't see the rigour behind it.

Comment: What does the book mean with functional relationship. If one can find a delta for each epsilon, we can select a function $\epsilon \mapsto \delta_\epsilon$ using the axiom of choice and this is always a function. I think the book means finding an explicit function. For example, in a proof you can see that for every epsilon, the value delta = epsilon/2 works and then your function is $\epsilon\mapsto \epsilon/2$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta No need for Choice. The set of possible $\delta$s for any given $\varepsilon$ is an interval, and on a set of intervals you can construct a choice function.

Comment: @Arthur. Can you give a reference for that? Thanks! New to choice stuff.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta It's straight-forward enough to prove: For any $\epsilon$ where the set of valid $\delta$ is $(0,\infty)$, pick $1$. For any other $\epsilon$, pick the midpoint of the interval of valid $\delta$ values. There, I've constructed a choice function. The axiom of choice is needed those times when you can't make such sweeping statements covering all cases at once, but instead you in some sense have to basically hand-pick each choice separately.

Comment: @Arthur I'll have to look up what a choice function is, but I believe this has set me on the right track. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *have* to do is to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is at least one $\delta>0$ which works. Theoretically, there is no need to supply one, only show that one exists.

However, in practice, given $\varepsilon$, actually supplying a $\delta$ that works turns out to be the most practical way to achieve this. So that's what we do not of the time: for any $\varepsilon>0$ we supply a single, concrete $\delta$. That happens to be exactly what a function is.

Comment: How would one approach proving a delta exists without supplying one? I'm more of a physics person, so I'm not well versed in set theory if that has something to do with it. I've taken two linear algebra classes that covered mappings from various vector spaces, bijections/isomorphisms, etc. If I don't know enough yet to understand your answer you can just tell me haha

Comment: @jwhitebored As I said, you usually _do_ supply a $\delta$. Generally, it is by far the easiest way to show that one exists. And this supplying is exactly a function. Honestly, I can't think of a time when I have proven a $\delta$ exists without actually supplying one. But in _theory_ it isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For a given $\epsilon >0$ you need to find a $\delta$ such that whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we get  $0\le |f(x)-L|<\epsilon $

As you see, we are given an $\epsilon$ and we are trying to find a $\delta$ which may or may not depend on $\epsilon$ which makes a relation hold.

Generally $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$  for example you may get $\epsilon = \delta/5$ but do not worry if you find a $\delta$ independent of $\epsilon$  as long as it works for you.

Comment: Could you give an example of an independent delta that aids the "for all epsilon" clause? I'm struggling to see how a single delta could be useful by itself when you must prove the "for all epsilon" part of the statement. I understand the game of "You pick an epsilon, and I'll find you a delta," but would a single delta independent of epsilon help to prove the limit exists? If so, an example would be great.

Comment: @jwhitebored Let $f(x)=4$ and prove that $\lim _{x\to 3} f(x)=4$.  Since $|f(x)-4|=0<\epsilon$,  you may pick any $\delta$ and it  works fine.